# Could time lock encryption be implemented through indistinguishable obfuscation?

Tags: encryption, protocol-design, timed-release

In the paper ["How to build time-lock encryption"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10623-018-0461-x), the authors give a theoretical solution to build time-lock encryption using multi-linear based witness encryption and blockchain. However, an instantiation of the construction is unfeasible to build because of the inefficiency of multi-linear maps.

So, if witness encryption based on multi-linear maps can't provide the efficiency required for the time-lock encryption, what alternatives are there? There are witness encryption schemes built from indistinguishable obfuscation, could time-lock encryption also be implemented using that?

Comment: I presume you mean [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10623-018-0461-x)? Please always link and / or uniquely reference papers. Could you take another look at your final sentence? The first to last sentence is also incomplete. Please edit so we can reopen the question.

Comment: What makes you think, that indistinguishability obfuscation can be implemented more efficiently than multi linear maps? I think you can construct them vice versa, if you throw in fully homomorphic encryption. On a very, very rough level, it is different sides of the same coin.

Answer (score 1):

Time-lock puzzles can be built from indistinguishability obfuscation through succinct randomised encodings: see the work of Bitansky et al. [BGJ+,BGL+] for more details.

[BGJ+]: Bitansky et al. [Time-Lock Puzzles from Randomized Encodings](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/514). ITCS'16

[BGL+]: Bitansky et al. [Succinct Randomized Encodings and their Applications](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/356). STOC'15