# Quantum-secure obfuscation

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptography, obfuscation

My question is a follow-up to [a recent question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80956/is-there-a-quantum-safe-time-lock) regarding quantum-secure time-lock puzzles (TLPs). TLPs can be built (in principle) from indistinguishability obfuscation (iO) [BGJ+,BGL+] as noted in [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70932/could-time-lock-encryption-be-implemented-through-indistinguishable-obfuscation/71047#71047) thread. As a corollary, quantum-secure iO would lead to quantum-secure TLPs (provided that there are inherently-sequential languages in the quantum world, which seems plausible).

So it boils down to whether any of the candidate constructions of iO are quantum-secure. It seems that some of the candidates are broken given a quantum computer [PM]. The question is whether any remaining candidate construction of iO is believed/conjectured to be quantum-secure?

[BGJ+]: Bitansky et al., [Time-Lock Puzzles from Randomized Encodings](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80956/is-there-a-quantum-safe-time-lock), ITCS'16

[BGL+]: Bitansky et al., [Succinct Randomized Encodings and their Applications](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70932/could-time-lock-encryption-be-implemented-through-indistinguishable-obfuscation/71047#71047), STOC'15

[PM]: Pellet-Mary, [Quantum Attacks against Indistinguishablility Obfuscators Proved Secure in the Weak Multilinear Map Model](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/533.pdf), Crypto'18

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that this was an open question. Brakerski et al. [BDGM] posted a paper today on the ePrint claiming the first (provable) post-quantum construction of iO. Their underlying security assumption is the "circular security" of an encryption scheme based on LWE.

[BDGM], Brakerski, Döttling, Garg and Malavolta, [Factoring and Pairings are not Necessary for iO: Circular-Secure LWE Suffices](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1024.pdf), ePrint Archive